# Bundle Error with rails 3.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, ruby-1.9.3

Previously i was working with following rails config:

```
RVM
ruby 1.9.2-p180
rails 3.0.10
Fedora 16
```

Recently i tried to install ruby 1.9.3 and then rails 3.2.2 on it in separate gemset. Installation of gems was ok. However i got this error when i tried to create a new rails app, i get this error:-

```
[puneet@puneet ~]$ rails new sample-app -d=mysql
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/mailers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
      create  app/models/.gitkeep
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/.gitkeep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
      create  test/functional
      create  test/functional/.gitkeep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.gitkeep
      create  test/unit
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
/home/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': /home/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: undefined symbol: d2i_ECPKParameters - /home/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:447:in `ssl'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:216:in `connection_for'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:358:in `request'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:135:in `fetch'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:162:in `fetch_dependency_remote_specs'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:122:in `fetch_remote_specs'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:70:in `specs'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in `block in remote_specs'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `each'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `remote_specs'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in `fetch_specs'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:205:in `block (2 levels) in index'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:202:in `each'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:202:in `block in index'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:198:in `index'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `resolve'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:122:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:48:in `run'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:12:in `install'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /home/puneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/bin/bundle:13:in `<main>'
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Thanks!
```

i Tried rails 3.2.1 and results where same. However when when i tried to use rails 3.2.1 with ruby-1.9.2-p180 it went smooth.

Appreciate any help !!

Answer (score 0):

rvm is picking up its global ruby and gems; the gems probably need to be updated for compatibility with ruby.  A simple solution may just be to run `bundle update` to get the latest versions of gems and dependencies.

You should probably first update the gem system first `gem update --system`.  And while you're at it `rvm get stable` to update rvm, too.

A more elegant solution is provided by rvm, creating a named gemset (not just the @global ones) specific to the version of ruby and rails.  See http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/ for the general idea.

Then create an `.rvmrc` file in your project directory to ensure you're always at the version  of everything your app expects.  http://beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/

This is a great way of having multiple versions of ruby, rails (and dependent gems) all on the same system.

Comment: Sorry for providing less info earlier. For reference i used http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html which covers pretty much everything. I'm also using separate gemset along with .rvmrc. However errors are same. I'm just confused how it's working perfect with ruby-1.9.2-p180.

Comment: OK, so the problem is likely to be an incompatibility with one of the gems listed in your Gemfile with _one of its dependent gems_.  It's hard to say from the stack dump, but perhaps an SSL issue?  Sometimes uninstalling a gem and its dependencies, then reinstalling with `bundle install` will correct the problem. Based on the stack dump, it does not appear that you are actually using a named gemset (which is a method of avoiding these kinds of conflicts) -- the dump reports that it is using `ruby-1.9.3-p125@global` which is the default set of gems from the system.